# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: when i return List of roles in Asp Core webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

**Hi**

I Need to user Dynamic Role Permission in `Asp Core` and `Angular6` with `Identity Core 2.2` by `Web Api`

When I Need to Return List of Roles for Show in  Dropdown it show me this Error :

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

**Now** :  How Can I Solve this Problem for return List of Roles ?

**This My Code :**

RoleManagerController :

```
private readonly IApplicationRoleManager _roleManag;

    public RoleManagerController(IApplicationRoleManager roleManag)
    {
        _roleManag = roleManag;
    }

   [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetRoles")]
    public async Task<List<Role>> GetRoles()
    {
        var res =await _roleManag.GetAllCustomRolesAsync();
        return res;
    }
```

IApplicationRoleManager :

```
 public interface IApplicationRoleManager : IDisposable
{
    Task<List<Role>> GetAllCustomRolesAsync();
}
```

ApplicationRoleManager :

```
 public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<Role>, IApplicationRoleManager
{

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IdentityErrorDescriber _errors;
    private readonly ILookupNormalizer _keyNormalizer;
    private readonly ILogger<ApplicationRoleManager> _logger;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<Role>> _roleValidators;
    private readonly IApplicationRoleStore _store;
    private readonly DbSet<User> _users;

    public ApplicationRoleManager(
        IApplicationRoleStore store,
        IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<Role>> roleValidators,
        ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
        ILogger<ApplicationRoleManager> logger,
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        IUnitOfWork uow) :
        base((RoleStore<Role, ApplicationDbContexct, int, UserRole, RoleClaim>)store, roleValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, logger)
    {
        _store = store;
        _store.CheckNullArgument(nameof(_store));

        _roleValidators = roleValidators;
        _roleValidators.CheckNullArgument(nameof(_roleValidators));

        _keyNormalizer = keyNormalizer;
        _keyNormalizer.CheckNullArgument(nameof(_keyNormalizer));

        _errors = errors;
        _errors.CheckNullArgument(nameof(_errors));

        _logger = logger;
        _logger.CheckNullArgument(nameof(_logger));

        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        _contextAccessor.CheckNullArgument(nameof(_contextAccessor));

        _uow = uow;
        _uow.CheckNullArgument(nameof(_uow));

        _users = _uow.Set<User>();
    }

     public async Task<List<Role>> GetAllCustomRolesAsync()
    {
        return await Roles.ToListAsync();
    }
```

**Edit**

New Error :

[Error...............................](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n07N5.png)

Startup :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.Configure<SiteSetting>(options => Configuration.Bind(options));
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContexct>(option =>
            option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationConnectionString")));
        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContexct>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddScoped<IApplicationRoleStore, ApplicationRoleStore>();
        services.AddScoped<RoleStore<Role, ApplicationDbContexct, int, UserRole, RoleClaim>, ApplicationRoleStore>();
        services.AddScoped<IApplicationRoleManager, ApplicationRoleManager>();
        services.AddScoped<RoleManager<Role>, ApplicationRoleManager>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork,ApplicationDbContexct>();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });
    }
```

Comment: Well, how does the json look like?

Comment: @PeterBons it show me this in mozila : `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: If you access `GetRoles` from web browser or postman, will you get expected json? Check the web browser network tab to see the real response while request from angular. For async method, you need to call await to get the response which means change `public async Task<List<Role>> GetRoles()
    {
        var res = await _roleManag.GetAllCustomRolesAsync();
        return res;
    }`

Comment: @TaoZhou now it show me this error : `MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.get_SelectAsyncMethod()'.`

Comment: There is something wrong in your code while querying dbcontext. Where did you get this error? Check whether you got expected result for objects `var res`. In addition, check the result for `return Roles.ToListAsync();`

Comment: @TaoZhou i Edit the Question . Please Read it

Comment: What is `Roles.ToListAsync()`? Error is thrown in `Roles`. Share us complete demo to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @TaoZhou for return list of role from  tabel `AspNetRoles` .

Comment: Check `public async Task<List<Role>> GetAllCustomRolesAsync()
    {  var result = await Roles.ToListAsync();
        return await Roles.ToListAsync();
    }`, does result return expected value?

Comment: @TaoZhou `result=null` and still show me that error

Comment: Without any reproducable demo, I could not provide any further help.

Comment: @TaoZhou how can i show you reproducable demo?

Comment: You may try github.

Comment: @TaoZhou https://github.com/kia9372/DynamicRole    my project

Answer (score 1):

Why are using EntityFrameworkCore `2.2.0-preview3-35497` in `StoreFinal.csproj` file?

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0-preview3-35497" />
```

It's not compatible with the rest of the libraries that you are using. That's why you are getting the `MissingMethodException / method not found` error. Try to use the same versions everywhere and don't use preview versions now. Also use https://github.com/jerriep/dotnet-outdated to update your dependencies correctly and consistently.

```
dotnet outdated -u
```